# Why the "sum of permutation inversions" is a non-admissible heuristic for the 8-puzzle?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, puzzle

A heuristic h(N) is admissible if for every node N, 0 ≤ h(N) ≤ h∗(N) where h*(N) is the true cost to reach the goal state from N.

In my opinion, the true cost to reach the goal state from N is 21 for the below puzzle (based on the depth the A* algorithm gives us to find the solution for the puzzle). Or do I understand it wrong and something else is the "true cost to reach the goal state from n"? If I was wrong how can I find the true cost?

Based on my assumption in the following slide, the h3(N) should be admissible too but it's not. (slides from page 24 https://www.slideshare.net/SoheilKhodayari/heuristic-search-80898832)

[Admissible and non-admissible heuristic for the 8-puzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywiSC.png)

Comment: You will probably like the ability to post [typeset math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) here using $\LaTeX$ and `MathJax`.  In any case $h(N)$ seems to be a function from "states" $N$ to (real?) values, but it would be good to setup the problem by defining the states and being specific about the range of $h(N)$.

Comment: The title mentions "sum of permutation inversions" but this is not explicitly mentioned in the body of the Question.  The problem statement (setup and goal) should be fully provided in the body of the Question.

Answer (score 1):

An admissible heuristic must *never* overestimate the true distance to the goal. Finding a single case where the heuristic does not overestimate does not indicate that it is admissible, as it must not overestimate in *all* cases. Even if the sum of permutation inversions is indeed less than the true cost in some cases, that does not prove it's less than the true cost in all cases.

As a counterexample, consider the case where all pieces are in the correct position, except for the 6 which is slid down one space from where it should be. The true cost to the goal is of course 1 (just slide the 6 up), but the permutation inversion cost is 2, since the 6 is "out of order" with respect to both the 7 and 8. Since we have even a single example of the heuristic overestimating, it is not admissible. The permutation inversion count really just deals with misplacements in a 1-D vector, but that turns out to not an admissible heuristic when dealing with a 2-D problem. That the 6 is out of order with respect to 2 numbers in the 1-D vector does not imply that it takes at least 2 moves to "fix" in the 2-D setting.